# How Can I change this given Applet Code to Convert it to a desktop Application

Tags: java, swing, applet, desktop

How Can i change this ***Applet*** to Make/Convert it to an ***Application*** using JFrame??  I am new in java programming. And i actually don't know how to convert a java applet to a java desktop application. So, help me someone to convert this applet to an application.

```
 package kiloboltgame;

    import java.applet.Applet;
    import java.applet.AudioClip;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.Frame;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import kiloboltgame.framework.Animation;

    public class StartingClass extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener {

        enum GameState {
            Running, Dead
        }

        GameState state = GameState.Running;

        private static Robot robot;
        public static Heliboy hb, hb2;
        public static int score = 0;
        private Font font = new Font(null, Font.BOLD, 30);
        private static Background bg1, bg2;
        private Image image, currentSprite, character, character2, character3,
                characterDown, characterJumped, background, heliboy, heliboy2,
                heliboy3, heliboy4, heliboy5;
        private URL base;
        private Graphics second;

        private Animation anim, hanim;
        public static Image tilegrassTop, tilegrassBot, tilegrassLeft,
                tilegrassRight, tiledirt;
        private ArrayList<Tile> tilearray = new ArrayList<Tile>();

        @Override
        public void init() {
            setSize(800, 480);
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            setFocusable(true);
            Frame frame = (Frame) this.getParent().getParent();
            frame.setTitle("Action Robot");
            addKeyListener(this);

            try {
                base = getDocumentBase();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            character = getImage(base, "data/character.png");
            character2 = getImage(base, "data/character2.png");
            character3 = getImage(base, "data/character3.png");

            characterDown = getImage(base, "data/down.png");
            characterJumped = getImage(base, "data/jumped.png");

            heliboy = getImage(base, "data/heliboy.png");
            heliboy2 = getImage(base, "data/heliboy2.png");
            heliboy3 = getImage(base, "data/heliboy3.png");
            heliboy4 = getImage(base, "data/heliboy4.png");
            heliboy5 = getImage(base, "data/heliboy5.png");

            background = getImage(base, "data/background.png");

            tiledirt = getImage(base, "data/tiledirt.png");
            tilegrassTop = getImage(base, "data/tilegrasstop.png");
            tilegrassBot = getImage(base, "data/tilegrassbot.png");
            tilegrassLeft = getImage(base, "data/tilegrassleft.png");
            tilegrassRight = getImage(base, "data/tilegrassright.png");

            anim = new Animation();
            anim.addFrame(character, 1250);
            anim.addFrame(character2, 50);
            anim.addFrame(character3, 50);
            anim.addFrame(character2, 50);

            hanim = new Animation();
            hanim.addFrame(heliboy, 100);
            hanim.addFrame(heliboy2, 100);
            hanim.addFrame(heliboy3, 100);
            hanim.addFrame(heliboy4, 100);
            hanim.addFrame(heliboy5, 100);
            hanim.addFrame(heliboy4, 100);
            hanim.addFrame(heliboy3, 100);
            hanim.addFrame(heliboy2, 100);

            currentSprite = anim.getImage();
        }

        @Override
        public void start() {

            bg1 = new Background(0, 0);
            bg2 = new Background(2160, 0);
            robot = new Robot();
            hb = new Heliboy(340, 360);
            hb2 = new Heliboy(700, 360);

            // Initialize tiles
            try {
                loadMap("data/map1.txt");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

            Thread thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        }

        // Loading the tile map
        private void loadMap(String filename) throws IOException {
            ArrayList lines = new ArrayList();
            int width = 0;
            int height = 0;

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            while (true) {
                String line = reader.readLine();
                if (line == null) {
                    reader.close();
                    break;
                }
                if (!line.startsWith("!")) {
                    lines.add(line);
                    width = Math.max(width, line.length());
                }
            }
            height = lines.size(); // it represents the total arraylist value size

            for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
                String line = (String) lines.get(j);
                for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
                    System.out.println(i + " is i");
                    if (i < line.length()) {
                        char ch = line.charAt(i);
                        Tile t = new Tile(i, j, Character.getNumericValue(ch));
                        tilearray.add(t);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void stop() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.stop();
        }

        @Override
        public void destroy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.destroy();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (state == GameState.Running) {
                while (true) {

                    robot.update();
                    if (robot.isJumped() == true) {
                        robot.setDucked(false);
                        currentSprite = characterJumped;

                    } else if (robot.isJumped() == false) {
                        currentSprite = anim.getImage();
                    }
                    if (robot.isDucked() == true) {
                        currentSprite = characterDown;
                    }

                    ArrayList<Projectile> projectiles = robot.getProjectiles();
                    for (int i = 0; i < projectiles.size(); i++) {
                        Projectile p = (Projectile) projectiles.get(i);
                        if (p.isVisible() == true) {
                            p.update();
                        } else {
                            projectiles.remove(i);
                        }
                    }

                    updateTiles();

                    hb.update();
                    hb2.update();

                    bg1.update();
                    bg2.update();

                    animate();

                    repaint();

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(17);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (robot.getCenterY() > 500) {
                        state = GameState.Dead;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void animate() {
            anim.update(10);
            hanim.update(50);
        }

        // this update method is used for double buffering
        // and it's called autometically internally
        @Override
        public void update(Graphics g) {
            if (image == null) {
                image = createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
                second = image.getGraphics();
            }

            second.setColor(getBackground());
            second.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            second.setColor(getForeground());
            paint(second);

            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            if (state == GameState.Running) { // set for game state Running
                g.drawImage(background, bg1.getBgX(), bg1.getBgY(), this);
                g.drawImage(background, bg2.getBgX(), bg2.getBgY(), this);
                paintTiles(g);
                // g.drawRect((int)robot.rect.getX(), (int)robot.rect.getY(),
                // (int)robot.rect.getWidth(), (int)robot.rect.getHeight());
                // g.drawRect((int)robot.rect2.getX(), (int)robot.rect2.getY(),
                // (int)robot.rect2.getWidth(), (int)robot.rect2.getHeight());
                // g.drawRect((int)robot.rect3.getX(), (int)robot.rect3.getY(),
                // (int)robot.rect3.getWidth(), (int)robot.rect3.getHeight());
                // g.drawRect((int)robot.rect4.getX(), (int)robot.rect4.getY(),
                // (int)robot.rect4.getWidth(), (int)robot.rect4.getHeight());

                g.drawImage(currentSprite, robot.getCenterX() - 61,
                        robot.getCenterY() - 63, this);
                g.drawImage(hanim.getImage(), hb.getCenterX() - 48,
                        hb.getCenterY() - 48, this);
                g.drawImage(hanim.getImage(), hb2.getCenterX() - 48,
                        hb2.getCenterY() - 48, this);

                ArrayList<Projectile> projectiles = robot.getProjectiles();
                for (int i = 0; i < projectiles.size(); i++) {
                    Projectile p = (Projectile) projectiles.get(i);
                    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    g.fillRect(p.getX(), p.getY(), 10, 5);
                }

                g.setFont(font);
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.drawString("Score: " + Integer.toString(score), 640, 30);

                // Set for Enemy Health
                if (hb.enemyVisibility == true) {
                    g.drawString("Health: " + Integer.toString(hb.health), 450, 30);
                } else if (hb2.enemyVisibility == true) {
                    g.drawString("Health: " + Integer.toString(hb2.health), 450, 30);
                }

            } else if (state == GameState.Dead) { // set for game state Dead
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 480);
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.drawString("DEAD", 360, 240);
            }
        }

        private void updateTiles() {
            for (int i = 0; i < tilearray.size(); i++) {
                Tile t = (Tile) tilearray.get(i);
                t.update();
            }
        }

        private void paintTiles(Graphics g) {
            for (int i = 0; i < tilearray.size(); i++) {
                Tile t = (Tile) tilearray.get(i);
                g.drawImage(t.getTileImage(), t.getTileX(), t.getTileY(), this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                System.out.println("moving up");
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:

                if (robot.isJumped() == false) {
                    // currentSprite = anim.getImage();
                    robot.setDucked(true);
                    robot.setSpeedX(0);
                }
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                robot.moveLeft();
                robot.setMovingLeft(true);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                robot.moveRight();
                robot.setMovingRight(true);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
                robot.jump();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL:
                if (robot.isDucked() == false && robot.isJumped() == false) {
                    robot.shoot();
                    robot.setReadyToFire(false);
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

            switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                System.out.println("stop moving up");
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                currentSprite = character;
                robot.setDucked(false);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                robot.stopLeft();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                robot.stopRight();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:

                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL:
                robot.setReadyToFire(true);
                break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public static Background getBg1() {
            return bg1;
        }

        public static Background getBg2() {
            return bg2;
        }

        public static Robot getRobot() {
            return robot;
        }
    }
```

**How Can i change this *Applet* to Make/Convert it to an *Application* using JFrame??**  I am new in java programming. And i actually don't know how to convert a java applet to a java desktop application. So, help me someone to convert this applet to an application.

Comment: Remove `extends Applet` and use `extends JPanel`.  Take all the "applet" related code out into a separate class (which extends from an applet).  Create an instance of your `StartingClass` and add this to you applet.  Create another class, probably called `Main`, add the `public static void main(String[] args) {...}` method to it, within the `main` method, create an instance of `JFrame` and add an instance of `StartingClass` to it. Welcome to the wonderful world of "why you shouldn't extend directly from a top level container"

Comment: Some tips. Avoid the overuse of `static`, it's not going help you in the long run; Swing components are already double buffered, so you don't need to implement your own buffering strategy; `KeyListener` is a poor choice for getting key board input, consider using the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead; Swing is only single threaded, so be-careful when changing the state of any value the UI relies from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: how can i add an instance of a JPanel to an Applet @MadProgrammer ??  is it possible? if u  show me a demo,  it will be helpful.

Comment: `add(new JPanel());`, `JApplet` is just a special type of container

Comment: I'm really frustrated.I created a class that extends `JPanel` and passed it's object to the class that extends `Applet` and  i added the`JPanel` into the `init()` method like `add(panelName)`. Then i     created a `JFrame` in the `main()` method and added the `JPanel` object in the `Frame`. but it doesn't work. Where will i add it and how please tell me ? And also there is a `Frame` in the `init()` method. What this `Frame` is doing actually? @MadProgrammer

Comment: my Main method: `public static void main(String[] args) {
  PanelSet set = new PanelSet(); //class that extends JPanel;
     StartingClass myApplet = new StartingClass(); 
     Frame myFrame = new Frame("Applet Holder"); 
     myApplet.init(); myApplet.start(); 
     myFrame.add(myApplet, BorderLayout.CENTER);
     myFrame.setSize(800,480);
     myFrame.setVisible(true);`  @MadProgrammer

Comment: Really, don't just dump the applet onto a frame, the applet has more expectations then you just calling `init` and `start`.  Remove the core functionality from the applet and place in your custom class